# storing and retrieving colors with database, C# windows forms application

Tags: c#, database, winforms, colors, color-picker

I'm making a windows application with C#. I'm using the color dialog box for the user to select a color. I'd like to store that color in a database, and be able to retrieve it later on, and be able to use that color in the user interface.

What approach would you suggest to me?

Comment: Do you already have a database that you are using for this application?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best way will be to store the hex color in a database field `nvarchar(7)` ... the input would be `#ffffff` as an example. `varchar(6)` would work just as well, and take up less space in your DB. Just be sure to append the `#` in your code.

Since you need to convert it to/from a control color, you can use `System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(someHexColor)`

```
// Hex to Control Color
var myColor = "#[color from database]";
var myControlColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(myColor);

// Control Color to Hex
var colorBlue = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
var hexBlue = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(colorBlue);
```

Comment: +1 - although I believe a `varchar` would suffice since you're not worried about unicode for the RGB values.

Comment: @CAbbot, that's true... force of habit for me since I set everything up for localization... my bad.

Comment: but then how do I retrieve those values and set them to control colors?

Comment: The problem is converting the Color to #FFFFFF format and back easily. Color does not have a Static method like FromArgb that takes a hex string.

Comment: @Nick.  Yup, I like this solution simply because of the readability factor.  The other answer is good too, but I'd personally hate looking at a DB table with a big INT as a color :S

Comment: +1 for `nvarchar`! Why mess around with converting the perfectly good UTF-16 that C#, the .Net Framework, and Windows are using back-and-forth to some 1980s-era 8-bit codepage chosen at random when this particular database instance was installed?

Comment: one more thing, I'm using the ColorDialog to get the color from the user. how do I change the result to a hexadecimal value?

Comment: @Jeffrey, besides the fact that if you're worried about THIS TYPE of data filling up a db, then you must be dealing with a HUGE number of records. SQL Server Express will bottom out on it's record number limit before it bottoms out on data size on nvarchar(7). And SQL Server Standard doesn't have these arbitrary limits, and Hard Drive space is CHEAP CHEAP CHEAP!!!

Comment: @rock: seems like C# has no Hex function

Comment: did you try an import the system.drawing or the system.drawing.color namespace?  I don't have Visual Studio in front of me to test this... sorry.

Comment: system.drawing is there. but I don't think that has anything to do with Hex right? anyway, i found a way to get the hex code. i'll post it in my answer

Comment: This approach doesn't provide consistent results. `ToHtml` will sometimes return a hex value, and other times return the name of the colour (depending on if a name is available). And although I am sure `FromHtml` will translate either correctly, you do lose the consistency with the value stored in the database. Not to mention some colour names are greater than 7 characters

Comment: What about transparency? I use this method too. But now I want to store Alpha value of the color too, which ColorTranslator does not support.

Comment: @Mahmoodvcs   I'd put alpha in a separate field in the table, and check for null in the code.

Answer (score 5):

I use the functions System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb() and System.Drawing.Color.ToArgb() to convert the color from and to integer, and save it as int on the database

Comment: This too is a good method, however, I suppose I prefer to be able to look at the db and understand the content.

Answer (score 0):

i found a way to get the hex code of a selected color with ColorDialog

```
ColorDialog col = new ColorDialog();

col.ShowDialog();

string color = col.Color.ToArgb().ToString("x");

color = color.Substring(2, 6);

color = "#" + color;

MessageBox.Show(color);

button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(color);
```

Answer (score 0):

Way after the question was originally asked, but this might be useful. It allows you to convert between `Color` and `String` in a single function call, no matter whether the color is a `SystemColor`, a `KnownColor`, or straight `ARGB`. Code:

```
        public static Color Str2Color(string cS, Color oDefault)
        {
            string cColor;
            Color oColor;

            try
            {
                if ((cS == null) || (cS == ""))
                {
                    return oDefault;
                }
                if (cS.StartsWith("[SystemColor]"))
                {
                    cColor = cS.Substring(13);
                    oColor = Color.FromName(cColor);
                    return oColor;
                }
                else if (cS.StartsWith("[KnownColor]"))
                {
                    cColor = cS.Substring(12);
                    oColor = Color.FromName(cColor);
                    return oColor;
                }
                else if (cS.StartsWith("[ARGB]"))
                {
                    cColor = cS.Substring(6);
                    oColor = Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt32(cColor));
                    return oColor;
                }
                else
                    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return oDefault;
            }
        }


        public static string Color2Str(Color oColor)
        {
            // To note:
            // 1. System.Windows.SystemColors => [SystemColor]
            //      Examples: SystemColors.Control, SystemColors.Window, SystemColors.WindowFrame. These are synonymous with System.Drawing.SystemColors, and are defined in the Windows style selected by the user.
            // 2. Windows.UI.Colors => [KnownColor]
            //      Examples: Colors.AliceBlue, Colors.AntiqueWhite, Colors.Aqua, Colors.Aquamarine etc. These are named colors that I think are the same as those expressable in HTML
            // 3. ARGB => [ARGB]
            //      Example: #ffff77 - hex representation of the RGB colour scheme.
            string cColor;

            
            try
            {
                if (oColor.IsSystemColor)
                {
                    cColor = "[SystemColor]" + oColor.Name;
                }
                else if (oColor.IsKnownColor)
                {
                    cColor = "[KnownColor]" + oColor.Name;
                }
                else
                {
                    cColor = "[ARGB]" + oColor.ToArgb();
                }

                return cColor;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

I put it in a static "helper" class. Means you can store the value in a database in a human readable format, and human editable format (as long as you get the name right).